# Node orm2 socket integration

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, orm

**Local environment configuration**
Win 7 64bit
Nodeclipse
MySQL Workbench

**Application configuration**
NodeJS              0.10.5
Express Framework   3.4.7
orm                 2.1.19
mysql               2.0.0-alpha8

**Issue**
I need to integrate orm2 functionalities and models to the socket.io part of my exoress application, in order to obtain the 100% of potentiality of these two technologies together.

**Details**
As it is said in the [documentation](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) of the orm2 npm extension, there is an easy way to integrate orm to application express framework. For my add-to-cart functionality I wish I catch the addToCart emitted event and use the orm to update and persist the cart.
I have integrated orm into express with this code and creating the models:

```
var connection = dbConnectionParam.protocol+'://'+dbConnectionParam.username+':'+dbConnectionParam.password+'@'+
dbConnectionParam.host+'/'+dbConnectionParam.database+'?pool=true&debug=true';
app.use(orm.express(connection, {
    define: function (db, models) {
        models.Formato = db.define('...
```

From the main app file I have:

```
var SessionSockets = require('session.socket.io');
var sessionSockets = new SessionSockets(
        io, sessionStore, express.cookieParser(loadconfig.loadKey('secret')));
sessionSockets.on('connection', function(err, socket, session) {
    socket.on('addToCart', function(data) { ...
```

**Direct Question**
Is there a way to integrate orm to socket.io framework?
If there is not, moving model definitions into an external node-module may be a good way, but how can I tune the db-connections performance? Pooling should be enough ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the models using this steps.

1. create a global variable i.e var db = null;
2. In your page route, before returning the response, assign the db to the value of req.models i.e db = req.models
3. Retrieve db in your socket and work with your models.